# Displaying sets and subsets of a string

Tags: c++, c++11, binary, set, subset

I am trying to  find the subsets and output them with binary representation.

EXAMPLE:

```
000:EMPTY
001:C
010:B
011:B C
100:A
101:A C
110:A B
111:A B C
```

I have the following code that finds all subsets but not sure about the binary?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void recsub(string sofar, string rest){
  if(rest=="") cout<<sofar<<endl;
  else{
    recsub(sofar+rest[0], rest.substr(1)); //including first letter
    recsub(sofar, rest.substr(1)); //recursion without including first letter.
  }
}

void listsub(string str){
  recsub("",str);
}

int main(){
  listsub("abc");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: subsets of what? please state your question clearly!

Comment: Just have another string parameter, say `binary_sofar`. For the case where you include the first letter, append `'1'` to `binary_sofar`; when you don't include the letter, append `'0'`. Print it together with `sofar` when the original string is exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it other way around, generate `mask` first and then generate matching string.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void listsub(const string &str) {
    auto n = str.size();
    // iterate over every binary representation
    for (size_t k = 0; k < (1u << n); ++k) {
        string binary;
        string subset;
        // iterate over every bit from right to left
        for (size_t bit = n ; bit > 0; --bit) {
            bool has_bit = (k & (1 << (bit - 1)));
            binary.push_back(has_bit ? '1' : '0');
            if (has_bit) {
                subset.push_back(str[n - bit]);
            }         
        }
        cout << binary << ':' << subset << endl;
    }
}
int main() {
    listsub("abc");
    return 0;
}
```